# How can I get the name of caller class when the app goes from activityA to activityB?

Tags: android, android-intent, contextclassloader

I need a function that gets name of caller Class from current activity.
In fact, I want to know, how can I get the name of caller class  via getClassLoader function.

By the way, here is my previous question, but I didn't get any acceptable answer.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024809/get-intent-class-loader-i-want-to-set-text-a-textview-in-secondactivity-to-nam/39027658#39027658)

Comment: The answer on that question is correct. You cannot "get the name of caller class via getClassLoader function". You can pass in some identifier via an `Intent` extra.

Comment: @CommonsWare How can I check whether if the name of class *(which is called)* equals to classA, then do sth?

Comment: I do not know what "which is called" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare All I'm trying to do is getting the name of previous activity in current activity. I want to know the app has come in this activity from which activity? What the name of that activity?

Comment: "All I'm trying to do is getting the name of previous activity in current activity" -- then follow the instructions in the answer on your other question. "What the name of that activity?" -- if you mean "what is the simple Java class name of that activity?", call `getClass().getSimpleName()`, and use that for the value of the extra. So, for example, if you are creating the `Intent` in `ActivityA`, `getClass().getSimpleName()` returns the string `"ActivityA"`.

Comment: Opening a duplicate question is not the way to get a better answer to your original question. You could try cleaning up your original question or adding comments there. You have a perfectly acceptable answer on your original question.